# What is word "property:" in Attribute

Tags: c#, properties, attributes

Could you explain me what does word "property:" mean?

```
[property: NotifyParentProperty( true )]
public string Filename
{
  get;
  set;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that the Attribute is applied to the property.
In this specific case, it's redundant and could be left away.

This kind of element defines the [Attribute Target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3787ac0.aspx) and is mostly useful when the target can be ambiguous, such as the targets `method` and `return`. Visual Studio also generates Attributes using the target `assembly` in `AssemblyInfo.cs` which is a part of many project templates.

More Info and a list of possible Attribute Targets:
[*Disambiguating Attribute Targets (MSDN)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3787ac0.aspx)